# Owin with Oracle OAM

Tags: oracle, single-sign-on, owin

I am developing a "SignalR" application, in which I need Owin.
But at the same time the authentication will be handled by "Oracle OAM as SSO".

I will be getting the username along with other variables in the Request headers.
From which I can always create a Claims Identity as follows -

```
    public class UserPrincipal:ClaimsPrincipal
{
    public UserPrincipal(string username, string locationnumber)
    {
        var gi = new GenericIdentity(username, "Authentication");
        var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(gi);

        ci.AddClaim(new Claim("Location", locationnumber));
    }
}
```

This conversion is done in a CustomHttpModule.
Now how to notify the Owin context to use this claims identity.
Where in the middleware we will hook the claims identity and how?

Comment: What type of authentication is used in your Owin application? bearer tokens?

Comment: Basically the concept is, all authentications will be handled by Oracle OAM SSO. So, in that case I will want to just reuse the ClaimsIdentity/ClaimsPrincipal rather than implementing authentication in Owin.